# jq expression to merge

Tags: json, jq

I have the below JSON document from the Junos REST API. I am trying to simplify the document down to just a select few items. How would I accomplish this?

**Expected JSON:**

```
[
  {  "status": .member-status[0].data,
     "serial": .member-serial-number[0].data,
     "slot": .fpc-slot[0].data
  },
  ...
]
```

**Original JSON:**

```
{
  "member-status": [
    {
      "data": "Prsnt"
    }
  ],
  "member-id": [
    {
      "data": "0"
    }
  ],
  "fpc-slot": [
    {
      "data": "(FPC 0)"
    }
  ],
  "member-serial-number": [
    {
      "data": "serNo1"
    }
  ],
  "member-model": [
    {
      "data": "ex4400-24t"
    }
  ],
  "member-priority": [
    {
      "data": "255"
    }
  ],
  "member-mixed-mode": [
    {
      "data": "N"
    }
  ],
  "member-route-mode": [
    {
      "data": "VC"
    }
  ],
  "member-role": [
    {
      "data": "Master*"
    }
  ],
  "neighbor-list": [
    {}
  ]
}
{
  "member-status": [
    {
      "data": "NotPrsnt"
    }
  ],
  "member-id": [
    {
      "data": "1"
    }
  ],
  "fpc-slot": [
    {
      "data": "(FPC 1)"
    }
  ],
  "member-serial-number": [
    {
      "data": "serNo2"
    }
  ],
  "member-model": [
    {}
  ]
}
```

Comment: I can make a series of JSON dicts with this expression, but I need to retain the array: `| {serial: ."member-serial-number"[0].data, status: ."member-status"[0].data, slot: ."fpc-slot"[0].data }'`

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a Unix/Linux question but more of a JSON question

Comment: @NoTime It's a question about how to use the Unix utility `jq` to do a particular thing with a JSON document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be something like:

```
jq -s '
  map(
    {
      "status": ."member-status"[0].data,
      "serial": ."member-serial-number"[0].data,
      "slot"  : ."fpc-slot"[0].data
    }
  )' your-file.json
```

Or factorising code a little:

```
jq -s '
  map({
    "status": ."member-status",
    "serial": ."member-serial-number",
    "slot"  : ."fpc-slot"
  } | with_entries(.value |= .[0].data))' your-file.json
```

Or as your simplified key for all three happen to be the second `-`-separated word:

```
jq -s '
  map({"member-status", "member-serial-number", "fpc-slot"} |
  with_entries(.value |= .[0].data | .key |= split("-")[1]))' your-file.json
```

Which on your sample gives:

```
[
  {
    "status": "Prsnt",
    "serial": "serNo1",
    "slot": "(FPC 0)"
  },
  {
    "status": "NotPrsnt",
    "serial": "serNo2",
    "slot": "(FPC 1)"
  }
]
```

`-s` slurps the several concatenated JSONs in the input into one JSON array, and `map()` maps the specified object to each member. As an alternative to `map({...})`, you could also do `[ .[] | {...} ]` which iterates over the array members and builds a new array out of the result.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that the simple expression `with_entries(.value |= .[0].data)` simplifies the data quite a bit, but without renaming the specific keys that the user mentions. That may be enough for them, unless they really _need_ to rename the keys.

Comment: @Kusalananda, they've been renamed already in the input to `with_entries`

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood me. The renaming may not be needed, is what I'm saying, unless they really need to rename the keys (and I don't see why they do as you would have to hard-code the names for both new and old keys in the expression if you do).

Comment: @Kusalananda. OK. I'm with you now.